# Javascript object member reassignment of value

Tags: javascript, object, concatenation

I need to change a value in a javascript object.

```
var wba_product = {
    sku:'12ZB7',
    availability:'Usually ships in 1-2 business days',
}
```

I want to change this using javascript.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript>
if(wba_product.sku == '12ZB7') wba_product.availability + ' Items are charged to your credit card only when they ship. Your credit card will not be charged until the item is shipped to you. ';
</script>
```

But this syntax is not working.

Comment: I forgot to note. I can not change the var declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the developer at Amazon.

"You can't change the value this way, you have set the DOM element
directly, changing the json object only changes json object not the
DOM element."

Which is what I ended up doing. I concatenated with div.innerHtml += "My added copy";

J.

Answer (score 4):

Two points:

1. You have a trailing comma at the end of the `availability` member, IE doesn't tolerates that.
2. To assign values to variables and object members, use the `=` [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators).

---

```
var wba_product = {
    sku:'12ZB7',
    availability:'Usually ships in 1-2 business days' // notice the comma removed
}

if(wba_product.sku == '12ZB7') {
  wba_product.availability = 'new value';  // assign a new value
}
```

And if you want to concatenate a string at the end of the availability member, you can do it like this:

```
 wba_product.availability += ' concatenated at the end.';
```

Comment: I shortened the var declaration for brevity. the problem is not the comma.
 Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I told you only because is a common mistake.

Comment: By the way wba_product isn't an associative array, it's an object literal.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is

```
if(wba_product.sku == '12ZB7') {
    wba_product.availability += 'Items are charged to...';
}
```